# Moved to different country but want to keep a London IP

Tags: ip, geolocation

I temporarily moved from London to Milan.

Despite keeping Google Uk as preferred search engine; Because of the location; I get more feeds, ads, reviews, and events from the area of Milan.

What's the best way to keep my computer getting: feeds, ads, events etc.. from the London area ?

I use a macbook pro with OS X 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your own VPN server hosted in London (take a look at OpenVPN Access Server - it's free version will suit your needs), this, however, requires some administartion skills.

Or just buy a VPN service from a provider that has exit nodes in London and has client for MacOS X.